# What is exactly the difference between $\forall x \neg P(x)$ and $\neg \forall xP(x)$?

Tags: logic

Could you explain what is the difference  between $\forall x \neg P(x)$ and $\neg \forall xP(x)$  or $\exists x\neg P(x)$ and $\neg \exists x P(x)$ ?

Comment: **All** numbers are **not** *even* (i.e. are *odd*) is different from **Not all** numbers are *even*, which is *tue*, while the former is *false*.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$\neg(\forall x \, P(x))$: "it is not true that $P(x)$ holds for all $x$.
This means that there *may* be some $x$ for which $P(x)$ is true, but there *must be at least one* for which $P(x)$ is false.

On the other hand $\forall x\, \neg P(x)$ says that for all $x$, $P(x)$ must be false. There is *no* $x$ for which it is true.

A similar thing holds for the existential statement, since in fact $\neg(\forall x \, P(x))$ is logically equivalent to $\exists x\, \neg P(x)$ and $\forall x\, \neg P(x)$ is equivalent to $\neg(\exists x\,P(x))$.
This should be apparent once you think about it.

Answer (score 1):

$\neg \forall x \,P(x)$ is equivalent to $\exists x\,\neg P(x)$ (*not everything is blue* is equivalent to *something is not blue*), and $\neg \exists x \,P(x)$ is equivalent to $\forall x\, \neg P(x)$ (*nothing is unequal to itself* means the same thing as *everything is equal to itself*).

Each of the two equivalences implies the other.

Here's another way to look at it — each quantifier can be defined in terms of the other: $\exists\equiv\neg\forall\neg$, $\forall\equiv\neg\exists\neg$. (For example, $\exists x\, P(x)\equiv\neg\forall\neg\, P(x)$.)

From any of these four equivalences, the rest follow (because double negation "cancels out" in classical logic).

Answer (score 1):

While this may seem to be a trivial hint, I've repeatedly found it helpful when getting used to a new syntax to see how it's defined formally and which parts are then left out because they are thought to be obvious.

Let's now add all possible parentheses, let $P(x)$ be "$x$ is prime" for example.

- $\forall x\neg P(x)$ is in fact $\forall x(\neg (P(x)))$. Think of it as "for every $x$ it holds that (it is not true that ($x$ is a prime))".
- $\neg \forall x P(x)$ becomes $\neg (\forall x (P(x)))$. This says "it is not true that (for every $x$ it holds that ($x$ is a prime))".